# SQL Subselect with MAX in where clause convert to Informix

Tags: sql, informix

I have following query in MSSQL :

```
select
    c1.auftrnr
    ,MAX(DATUM) as Datum
    ,(select MAX(Zeit) from kaufedit where auftrnr=c1.auftrnr and datum=max(c1.datum)) as Zeit
from kaufedit c1
group by c1.auftrnr
order by c1.auftrnr
```

This selects for every order the maximum day , and for that maximum day the maximum time . In order to check if something changed. This works really good and fast.

I am trying to convert this into Informix , but till now I was unable to make it work .

**UPDATE 1**

12.10.FC14WE is the version
datum is date(10)
zeit is char(5)
both cannot be changed :(

I have tried following :

```
select extend(datum, year to second)+(zeit - DATETIME(00:00) hour to minute) as datumzeit from kaufedit
```

Comment: can you share your coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: Don't tag SQL server since you're not looking for a solution in SQL server.

Comment: Also post what error you are receiving in Informix.

Comment: Which version of Informix are you using?  As long as it is 12.10 or 14.10, it won't matter much, but earlier versions may have problems that these later versions don't.  Your query doesn't work with 14.10 as written, generating error -595 "Bad use of aggregate in this context".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best, IMO, if you combined the Datum and Zeit columns into a single DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND value.  You would simply need the maximum of the combined column for each order.

However, assuming that's not an option and that you do have a sufficiently recent version of Informix, then you can use a CTE — common table expression — like this:

```
WITH t1 AS
    (SELECT auftrnr, MAX(datum) AS datum
       FROM kaufedit
      GROUP BY auftrnr
    )
SELECT c1.auftrnr,
       c1.datum,
       MAX(c1.zeit) AS zeit
  FROM kaufedit AS c1
  JOIN t1 ON t1.auftrnr = c1.auftrnr AND t1.datum = c1.datum
 GROUP BY c1.auftrnr, c1.datum
 ORDER BY c1.auftrnr, c1.datum;
```

The CTE derives the order number and maximum date for the order.  The main query then joins that result with the main table, yielding the desired output.

**Schema and Data**
The data format assumes that you set DBDATE='Y4MD-' or equivalent in the environment.  Alternatively, change the DATE type to DATETIME YEAR TO DAY.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS kaufedit;

CREATE TABLE kaufedit
(
    auftrnr     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    datum       DATE NOT NULL,
    zeit        DATETIME HOUR TO SECOND NOT NULL,
    information VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO kaufedit(auftrnr, datum, zeit, information)
    VALUES(123, '2022-01-01', '01:23:45', 'Entered at 2022-01-01T01:23:45');
INSERT INTO kaufedit(auftrnr, datum, zeit, information)
    VALUES(123, '2022-01-01', '10:22:44', 'Entered at 2022-01-01T10:22:44');
INSERT INTO kaufedit(auftrnr, datum, zeit, information)
    VALUES(123, '2022-01-01', '11:32:54', 'Entered at 2022-01-01T11:32:54');
INSERT INTO kaufedit(auftrnr, datum, zeit, information)
    VALUES(123, '2022-01-01', '21:17:05', 'Entered at 2022-01-01T21:17:05');

INSERT INTO kaufedit(auftrnr, datum, zeit, information)
    VALUES(321, '2022-01-02', '01:23:45', 'Entered at 2022-01-02T01:23:45');
INSERT INTO kaufedit(auftrnr, datum, zeit, information)
    VALUES(321, '2022-01-02', '17:22:44', 'Entered at 2022-01-02T17:22:44');
INSERT INTO kaufedit(auftrnr, datum, zeit, information)
    VALUES(321, '2022-01-03', '11:32:54', 'Entered at 2022-01-03T11:32:54');
INSERT INTO kaufedit(auftrnr, datum, zeit, information)
    VALUES(321, '2022-01-03', '11:57:05', 'Entered at 2022-01-03T11:57:05');

INSERT INTO kaufedit(auftrnr, datum, zeit, information)
    VALUES(444, '2022-02-02', '01:23:45', 'Entered at 2022-02-02T01:23:45');
INSERT INTO kaufedit(auftrnr, datum, zeit, information)
    VALUES(444, '2022-03-02', '10:22:44', 'Entered at 2022-03-02T10:22:44');
INSERT INTO kaufedit(auftrnr, datum, zeit, information)
    VALUES(444, '2022-04-03', '11:32:54', 'Entered at 2022-04-03T11:32:54');
INSERT INTO kaufedit(auftrnr, datum, zeit, information)
    VALUES(444, '2022-05-03', '21:57:05', 'Entered at 2022-05-03T21:57:05');
```

**Output**

```
123  2022-01-01  21:17:05
321  2022-01-03  11:57:05
444  2022-05-03  21:57:05
```

(Tested on Linux RHEL 7.4 with Informix 14.10.FC1.)

---

**Extension**

If you want the extra information in the `kaufedit` table, then you might use a query such as:

```
WITH t1 AS
    (SELECT auftrnr, MAX(datum) AS datum
       FROM kaufedit
      GROUP BY auftrnr
    ),
     t2 AS
    (SELECT c1.auftrnr, c1.datum, MAX(c1.zeit) AS zeit
       FROM kaufedit AS c1
       JOIN t1 ON t1.auftrnr = c1.auftrnr AND t1.datum = c1.datum
      GROUP BY c1.auftrnr, c1.datum
    )
SELECT c1.auftrnr, c1.datum, c1.zeit, c1.information
  FROM kaufedit AS c1
  JOIN t2
    ON c1.auftrnr = t2.auftrnr
   AND c1.datum = t2.datum
   AND c1.zeit = t2.zeit
 ORDER BY c1.auftrnr, c1.datum;
```

**Output**

```
123  2022-01-01  21:17:05  Entered at 2022-01-01T21:17:05
321  2022-01-03  11:57:05  Entered at 2022-01-03T11:57:05
444  2022-05-03  21:57:05  Entered at 2022-05-03T21:57:05
```

Comment: Hello, I have 12.10.FC14WE . The datum field is date(10) and unfortunately the zeit field is char(5) . I cannot change this ( not allowed ). I have tried your first query (copy paste) and I get a Syntax Error has occurred. I have also tried to combine the two fields , but I guess I am doing something wrong : select extend(datum, year to second)+(zeit - DATETIME(00:00) hour to minute) as datumzeit from kaufedit , but I get an erro a field in a datetime or interval value is incorrect or an illegal operation specified on datetime field.

Comment: I accepted your solution , even if it did not directly help me . It pointed me at least in the right direction ! Thank you.

Comment: Informix added support for the WITH clause (CTE) in 14.10.  It is important to identify versions and to give a schema (and some sample data, along with the expected output).  It guides those who would help you in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is :

datum is date(10)
zeit is char(5)

the solution was :

```
select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(datum,%d-%m-%Y)|| ' ' || || zeit || ':00',"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S))
```

This works great with MAX and group by.